# Find and replace capture group inside file

Tags: windows-7, powershell, find-and-replace

I'm trying to read a text file, doesn't matter what language ...

```bsh
$x = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("__init__.py")
```

... [find a string](https://regex101.com/r/tC6iM0/1)

```bsh
$pattern = [regex] '(?s)(?:ExportSTL.+?global_scale = .+?default=)(.+?),'
```

... and replace the capturing group (`(.+?)`) with another string (for instance `10.0`). Then write to the file and close it.

How can I get at the capturing group in a way that I can modify it in place and save the file? All my attempts replace the whole matched line, with the non-capturing group.

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and don't answer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [positive lookbehind group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of the non-capturing group:

```
$pattern = [regex] '(?s)(?<=ExportSTL.+?global_scale = .+?default=)(.+?),'
```

The lookbehind group will be required to match, but it won't consume any characters.

The replacement string will be just `'10.0'`.

A less exotic way would be to turn the non-capturing group into a normal group:

```
$pattern = [regex] '(?s)(ExportSTL.+?global_scale = .+?default=)(.+?),'
```

The replacement string would be `'${1}10.0'` (with single quotes). The `${1}` represents the first group. (You need the curly brackets around the "1" so that it doesn't run into the "10.0".)

Comment: The positive lookbehind doesn't work here - _Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed_. The curly brackets `${1}` work, this is what I was missing.

Comment: @Leeroy, I believe that lookbehinds can be of variable width in PowerShell and .NET. It's true that they have to be of fixed width in some other flavors of regex, such as in Boost (C++).

Comment: Oh sorry I see you're right, variable width lookbehinds are supported. I can get a match with your regex, `1 --- 1.0` and `0 --- 1.0,`. I can't seem to get it to substitute correctly tho. `-replace $pattern,  '10.0'` changes all instances of `default=something`, instead of just that one with `1.0`

Comment: @Leeroy, here's an example. Try executing this: `'123abc' -replace '(?<=123)(abc)','xxx'`  It replaces the "abc" with "xxx". If you change the "123" in the original string, the replacement doesn't happen. (But In any case, I think the second way with the `$1` replacement is probably better because more people would understand it.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Thanks to [@dangph](https://superuser.com/users/10120/dangph), here is the script with his suggestion put in.

```
$x = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("__init__.py")
# Turned the non-capturing group into a normal group
$pattern = [regex] '(?s)(ExportSTL.+?global_scale = .+?default=)(.+?),'
# Put $1 in curly brackets, and added literal comma at end of replacement
$x -replace $pattern, '${1}10.0,' | Set-Content .\__init__.py
```

[Updated Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tC6iM0/2)